# jQuery Slidetoggle + rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, slidetoggle

Hi I am trying to make so when you click on a class it will slidetoggle another class and also rotate the class you just clicked on. My code do all that but if I click again it dont rotate back.

```
/* Category Description Toggle */
$('.category-desc').css("display", "none");
$(".category-desc-toggle").addClass("close");

$(".category-desc-toggle").click(function() {
$('.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
if($('.category-desc-toggle').hasClass('close')){
$(this).transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
$('.category-desc-toggle').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
};
if($('.category-desc-toggle').hasClass('open')){
$(this).transition({ rotate: '0deg' });
$('.category-desc-toggle').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
};
```

});

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which plugin are you using for rotation ?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$(".category-desc-toggle").click(function() {
    $('.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
});
```

Comment: Nope, that did not work. Well I think it's better setting display none in jQuery, becuse you get so much CSS code you dont remember why display none was there anyway. I also clean up my code to do so much LESS coding as possible. Becuse if you delete that display in CSS the jQuery stop working. Thanks for the reply Ronnie.

Comment: And also, make sure your transition plugin is loading properly,... I don't have any experience with it.. But instead I tried changing the transition (in my code) with a toggle() and it worked well.... You should also check if any other function is happening or not.. if it is, then problem is in transition.. otherwise, problem is in the parent.

Comment: The code you coded, do the same as my code, but I am trying to make the class you click on to rotate back to it's original stance.

Answer (score 0):

in the .category-desc-toggle in your HTML document add this onclick="count_click_desc=(count_click_desc+1)%2;"

```
$(".category-desc-toggle").click(function() {
$('.category-desc').slideToggle(300);
if(count_click_desc){
    $(this).transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
};
if(!count_click_desc){
    $(this).transition({ rotate: '-45deg' });
};
});
```

Again, it **should** work, I don't have the transition plugin installed and is lazy to download it... So, I', not sure it will work or not... Actually, I have not read ur question properly before.. If solved, plz click +1

Comment: Lets keep everything in the same file, I updated my code. Now it do something everytime I click on the element. But it dont stay in that position.

Comment: I don't know the whole scenario.. I know just the part you marked and it should do its job.. If not doing... I surrender.. also try to change the -45deg to 315deg (simply avoiding negative degrees).. If it broke it... do  some research on your own

Answer (score 0):

I think you should then add -45deg instead 0deg... And also, make sure the class is not positioned static